# Cut with one specific interval

Tags: r, cut

I have a dataset and I want to cut it into 4 parts using cut() function (or something similar).

```
set.seed(5)
cut(runif(100, 0, 100), 4)
```

gives levels: (1.35,25.8] (25.8,50.2] (50.2,74.6] (74.6,99]

The thing is, I want one interval to be (25.8,50] and another (50,74.6]. Actually, rest may vary a bit, but this 50 is important for me. How to achieve it?

Comment: Why don't you manually specify the breaks? `breaks` can be a numeric vector specifying the desired break points.

Comment: I will be using various datasets, in some of them distribution may differ a lot, that's why I don't want to use fixed breaks

Comment: @jedrekwol how will you decide the breaks? Can you know it from the data? Could you create a function that calculates the breaks, like `c(min(data), quantile(data, 0.25), 50, quantile(data, 0.75), max(data))`?

Comment: If your data has min of 0 and max 0f 100 and you have two middle intervals, you just have to find the min and max of your data. [min_data, 25.8] and [74.6. max_data] should be the other two intervals.

Comment: @allan-cameron this is actually good. The skewness of datasets may differ, so 50 sometimes will be in first or last interval, but I can sort it the breaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using cut, then the  the **first break has to be smaller than the min(data)**. Otherwise, there will be a NA in the intervals.

For example using quantiles,

```
cut(data, breaks= c(min(data) - diff(range(data)) / 1000,
                                             quantile(data)[2:5]))
```

Also, you already know the two middle intervals (25.8 - 50 and 50 - 74.6), its then just finding the min and max of the data

```
cut(data, breaks= c(min(data) - diff(range(data)) / 1000, 
                                        25.8, 50, 74.6, max(data)))
```

Comment: It might be better to scale it slightly, which is what `cut.default` does - e.g. `min(data) * 0.99` rather than having a fixed offset.

Comment: @thelatemail I initially changed to what you suggested. Then I realized  that if `min(data)` is zero, there is a problem. I think `min(data) - diff(range(data)) / 1000` is what `cut.default` do.